# Coldfusion - Error page tells me I'm missing and ending tag but I have it

Tags: coldfusion

Here is my code:

```
<cffunction name="onRequest">
    <cfargument name="templatename">

    <cflogin>
        <cfif form.submit IS NOT "">
            <cfif form.username IS "user" AND form.username IS "pass">
                <cfloginuser name="#form.username#" password="#form.password#" roles="admin">
            <cfelse>
                <cfset request.errorMessage = "Wrong username or password. Please try again.">
                <cfinclude template="login.cfm">
                <cfreturn>
            </cfif>
        <cfelse>
            <cfinclude template="login.cfm">
            <cfreturn>
        </cfif>
    </cflogin>
    <cfinclude template="#arguments.templatename#">
</cffunction>
```

I am getting the following error:

```
Context validation error for the cfargument tag.

The tag must be nested inside a CFFUNCTION tag.

The error occurred in C:/ColdFusion11/cfusion/wwwroot/myApp/administrator/Application.cfc: line 9
 7 : 
 9 :        <cfargument name="templatename">
10 : 
11 :        <cflogin>
```

Can anyone help me?

I'm using ColdFusion 11 Trial

Comment: Try it without the entire cflogin block.  You will eventually have to move it anyway.

Comment: I suppose you'd tell us if login.cfm contained some cfarguments :). Since your code appears to be syntactically correct, have you tried removing the `<cfreturn>` tags? I use Railo, so can't test intricacies with CF, but perhaps CF is upset at you for trying to dodge the implicit include?

Comment: What's in the include files? if you have cfarguments in the include files you will likely throw an error.

Comment: Also, I personally don't change variable names of built-in functions like this but Railo will let me, but perhaps you should pull the syntax right out the docs. `<cffunction name="onRequest" returnType="void"> <cfargument name="targetPage" type="String" required=true/>` and change the variable name on the last line to #targetPage# to match. Not likely the problem, but if login.cfm doesn't contain arguments, this is the only problem that I could almost see throwing that error. Using Railo myself, I can't nail this as ACF-problem or not.

Comment: Pls include the preceding function's code too. Parser errors sometimes don't quite get the location of the problem right.

Answer (score 0):

Here in this code-

```
 <cfif form.username IS "user" AND form.username IS "pass">
    <cfloginuser name="#form.username#" password="#form.password#" roles="admin">
```

You are checking the form.username twice with two values with a "AND" operator.
That should be like this I think:-

```
   <cfif form.username IS "user" AND form.password IS "pass">
     <cfloginuser name="#form.username#" password="#form.password#" roles="admin">
```